# Unsequenced function calls: error for a #define

Tags: c++, function-call, define-syntax

A static code analysis tool shows me that I have an unsequenced function calls for a define. Want to get rid of the warning.

It complains that I use Logging() and get_id() (two functions, only one allowed) in the last define.

```
#define MSG_FORMAT(x) " [thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] [" << __func__ << "] " << x

#define SYSTEM_LOG(x) loa::peer::Logging() << MSG_FORMAT(x)
```

How can I modify the defines to avoid the warning? As you see I have already tried to split them into two defines.

Comment: This looks like a really bad idea. Why do you use macros? Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). How do you use the macro? Where do you use the macro? With what parameter? What is the context? `code analysis tool shows me` - what tool? and what is the exact warning message, including filename and line number?

Comment: The unsequencedness shouldn't matter. Silly warning. Just disable it!

Comment: @KamilCuk "Why do you use macros?" - should be obvious from the code that he wants to include the function name in every log message, which necessitates a macro.

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to allow further chaining of `<<`? (Such as `SYSTEM_LOG("foo") << 123 << "abc";`)

Comment: Since macros are resolved at (or, traditionally, *before*) compile time, splitting the macro can’t possibly introduce ordering on a runtime operation.

Comment: Thank you for all answers. In the future, this code will be exchanged with a proper logger (company generic c++ logger) but I wanted to know if the warning was an issue for the coming release. For now I will try to justify the warning.